# Can you update a remote web sql database securely?

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, firewall

We have sql 2000 databases on our internal network secured behind ISA Firewall. Up till now we have not opened tcp port 1433 to allow external sql traffic in or out. We also have a remote external website with a later version of sql on.

Is there any way to update the external database from our internal network without increasing the chance of anyone hacking into our internal network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx) does this for most cases. I'd recommend against opening up your firewall to allow anyone to connect to your database server - that's pretty much inviting hackers to own your data.

The Sync framework works natively with [SQL Server 2000 SP4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281959%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and later - though you can probably find a provider for older versions if you try. By using a provider framework, Sync can in principle connect to any data source.